# Selenium screenshot does not contain whole page

Tags: perl, selenium, screenshot

I'm automating a page (with Perl), which contains:

```
<object odebase="/3Dviewer/partserver/applets/partwebviewer/partwebviewer.exe" style="width:100%; height:100%" id="cnsweb3d" data="" type="application/x-zjv"></object>
```

in an iframe. I have to take a screenshot from the whole page. I tried `capture_screenshot`, but here I see only a white field, where I expect the object above is shown. It's not a matter of timing, the content is already rendered. When I take a screenshot with `Imager::Screenshot` before and after `capture_screenshot` I see what I expect to see.
How do you handle this?

Changing the page source is not a solution here, I can't influence it.

Comment: I'm using selenium server 2.46.0

Comment: Typo: `<object codebase=...` instead of <object odebase=...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium firefox driver take window screenshot(not fullscreen)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997060/selenium-firefox-driver-take-window-screenshotnot-fullscreen)