# Selenium firefox driver take window screenshot(not fullscreen)

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I have a fully working Python script for taking screenshots of webpages using selenium and the FF driver(windows).

The script is taking full page screenshots instead of let's say 1024x768, which make the process slow. Here is my code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.set_window_size(1024,768)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("%s/%s.png"%(screen_dir,o.netloc))
    driver.close()
```

Any ideas on how to make selenium/firefox take above the fold screenshots and not full page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how the "take screenshot" functionality is working in Firefox - *it would take a screenshot of a complete page from top to bottom* even if part of it is not visible. This is actually not how it supposed to work by the [specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-take-screenshot).

Chrome [would take a screenshot of the visible area / viewport only](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294). Switch to it.

Comment: so its not implemented/bug of FF or Selenium-FF drivers. Guess i have to switch. Thanks!

Comment: @Theodoros80 well, I actually like this behavior (sometimes it's really good to have a complete page screenshot). But the spec says that the " top-level browsing context’s viewport." should be taken on the screenshot. Hope chrome would do the job in your use case.